# uploading remote server files to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to pull events files that exists persistent storage on remote server into google cloud server.
The gsutil and python api only support to upload if the code will run
on the server with the files.

I can't run the code on the local sever, i can only run code on external server.

Comment: It sounds like your files exist on the "local server", can you confirm that's correct?  What mechanism do you have for the external server to access those files on the local server?

Comment: No, the files not exist on the server that i want to run the pulling code.
I'm open mind for any kind of mechanism as long the code will run outside the server location of the files.

Comment: The machine running code needs some way to access the files to be able to upload them.